# Scala Parser Combinator Replace Patterns

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I got a below program, I can parse the pattern like `convert(a.ACCOUNT_ID, string)` to the expression, but I want to replace this pattern with `CAST(a.ACCOUNT_ID AS VARCHAR)`. I can do parse the result expression and replace the strings with the one above but there are expressions like this hence I don't want to do that way.. Is there any way that I can do a pattern replace? Like if I find a pattern as `convert(a.ACCOUNT_ID, string)` then replace it with `CAST(a.ACCOUNT_ID AS VARCHAR)`

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.token._
import scala.util.parsing.input.CharSequenceReader


trait QParser  extends RegexParsers with JavaTokenParsers  {
  def knownFunction: Parser[Any] = ident ~ "(" ~ ident ~ ("." ~ ident <~ "," ~ ident ~ ")")

  def parse(inputString: String): Any = synchronized {
    phrase(knownFunction)(new CharSequenceReader(inputString)) match {
      case Success(result, _) => result
      case Failure(msg,_) => throw new DataTypeException(msg)
      case Error(msg,_) => throw new DataTypeException(msg)
    }
  }

 class DataTypeException(message: String) extends Exception(message)

}

object Parser extends QParser {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
     println(parse("convert(a.ACCOUNT_ID, string)"));
  }
}
```

Output: `(((convert~()~a)~(.~ACCOUNT_ID))`

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want to "replace"  `convert(a.ACCOUNT_ID, string)` with `CAST(a.ACCOUNT_ID AS VARCHAR)`? That you want to parse it into the same representation? In that case it should be noted that you're not current parsing `CAST(a.ACCOUNT_ID AS VARCHAR)` at all.

Comment: Say I have a long sql string with some pattern `convert(ident.ident, ident)` ex. "select convert(a.ACCOUNT_ID, string) from dual". I want to convert it to "select cast(a.ACCOUNT_ID AS VARCHAR) from dual"

Comment: I see. I suppose I was confused because currently your parser don't produce strings as their result and I did not realize that that was the intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you mean with *"there are expressions like this hence I don't want to do that way"*, but you can transform the result of your parser function using the `^^` operator.

A transformation function for your parser could be :

```
def knownFunction: Parser[String] = 
  ident ~ "(" ~ ident ~ "." ~ ident ~ "," ~ ident ~ ")" ^^ {
    case func ~ "(" ~ obj ~ "." ~ value ~ "," ~ castType ~ ")" =>
      val sqlFunc = Map("convert" -> "CAST")
      val sqlType = Map("string" -> "VARCHAR")
      s"${sqlFunc(func)}($obj.$value AS ${sqlType(castType)})"
  }
```

Using this updated function, the output of your application would be :

```
CAST(a.ACCOUNT_ID AS VARCHAR)
```

More information about the Scala Combinator Parsing can be found in a [chapter](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combinator-parsing.html) of *Programming in Scala, 1ed*.

Comment: @Sathish Don't forget to accept / upvote helpful answers in this and your previous questions.